# Rebind @ConfigurationProperties object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am using spring cloud consul and config in my application and I am able to refresh any object which has `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated when the config has changed in consul.

But I just want to know, is there any way I can control whether to refresh or not even the config in the consul has changed (for example I will has a boolean set to true in the consul config to trigger the rebind and set to false to not trigger the rebind?)? I know I can use `@EventListener` with the `EnvironmentChangeEvent` to do some stuff but not sure what exactly need to implement there.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but by default, there is a watch set on the config root. The watch will refresh objects when changed. It can be disabled.

Comment: That's not how it works. You'll have to disable the watch and setup something on your own.